# How do I detect if a value is an enum instance in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums

Here is my first try:

```
enum class Color { R, G, B}

fun main() {
    val x: Any = Color.R
    println(x::class.isInstance(Enum::class))
}
```

it prints `false` :-( when I expect it to return `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood the behaviour of `isInstance` with respect to its receiver and parameter. Check the documentation:

> Returns true if value is an instance of this class on a given platform.

This means that the expression `someClass.isInstance(someValue)` checks whether `someValue` is an instance of `someClass`.

In your case, with `x::class.isInstance(Enum::class)`, you're NOT asking *"Is `x` an instance of the `Enum` class?"*, you're asking *"Is the `Enum` class object an instance of the class of `x`?"*. and this is false because the `Enum` class object is an instance of `KClass<Enum<*>>`, not an instance of `Color`.

If you want to check whether `x` is an instance of `Enum` by using this same function, you should instead do:

```kotlin
Enum::class.isInstance(x)
```

But because you statically know the class you're testing for (`Enum`), you can also do more simply:

```kotlin
x is Enum<*>
```

Here is a playground link to test this: https://pl.kotl.in/UCgIdl8lM

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joffrey's answer this is the working code:

```
enum class Color { R, G, B}
fun main() {
    val x: Any = Color.G
    if (x is Enum<*>) {
        println(x.ordinal)
    }
}
```